# Serilog Additional Properties

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, serilog

I work working with Serilog and logging events to SQL Server (using the Serilog, Serilog.Framework.Logging and Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer libraries).

As part of an MVC6 application, when I log events and set the option to include properties, I see some additional properties in the XML column.

If I issue something like the following statement:

```
Log.Information("{Property1}", "Value1");
```

I see something like the following in the Properties column:

```
<properties>
  <property key="Property1">Value1</property>
  <property key="SourceContext">WebApplication4.Controllers.BaseController</property>
  <property key="ActionId">1b9f9c7e-7c5c-4b14-a30d-99f2ebc88c51</property>
  <property key="RequestId">80000191-0001-f000-b63f-84710c7967bb</property>
</properties>
```

Where do these extra properties come from?  Can I set additional properties similar to these?  If so, where do I set them?  I can set additional properties if I include them in the message (similar to Property1 above) but I might want to include additional properties that are not in the message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three ways to go about this.

The first is to use `ForContext()` to create a logger instance with specific properties attached:

```
var specific = Log.ForContext("SomeProperty", 42);
specific.Information("This has properties attached");
```

The second is using enrichers:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.WithMachineName()
    // Other config...
```

The third is the `LogContext`.

```
using (LogContext.PushProperty("SomeProperty", 42))
{
    Log.Information("This has properties attached");
}
```

Some minor setup is required for this, check out the info on the [Serilog wiki](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment).

Comment: I remember reading about the first two options but, for some reason, the information did not stick.  The last option was new to me and looks like the most desirable option for the moment.  One of the other questions I had asked is where do the extra properties when using MVC (ActionId, RequestId, etc.) come from?  Where are they *injected*?  What do they represent?  I have looked through the code a bit but do not recall seeing where they are set.  At any rate, I have marked the information you provided as the answer.  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. The web-related properties you often see come from: https://github.com/serilog-web/classic.