# .NET Core Serilog username is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I have added this middleware to add usernames to my logging, however, it always appears as null.

This is the middleware

```
private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public LogUserName(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", context.User.Identity.Name);
        await next(context);
        //return next(context);
    }
```

I call it in Program.cs and Startup.cs like this

Program.cs

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
 .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
 .Enrich.FromLogContext()
 .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("Microsoft"))
 .Filter.ByExcluding(Matching.FromSource("System"))
 .CreateLogger();
```

Startup.cs

```
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseMiddleware<LogUserName>();
```

I noticed that when I hardcoded a property, it would appear in my log under the properties tag. E.g

```
LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", "Test");

<properties><property key='SourceContext'>AAAA.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel</property><property key='ActionId'>e477aa96-f0b5-4790-9253-80fcbc72fbda</property><property key='ActionName'>/Account/Login</property><property key='RequestId'>0HLJ6EBJ4V6PP:00000002</property><property key='RequestPath'>/Identity/Account/Login</property><property key='CorrelationId'></property><property key='ConnectionId'>0HLJ6EBJ4V6PP</property><property key='UserName'>Test</property></properties>
```

Also, I would like to bring it out of the properties tag and into its own field if possible.

Comment: Just to clarify where the problem is: Logging the username generally works and appears in your Serilog logs? E.g. when you set some static value inside of your middleware, it works properly? But when the middleware is executed, `context.User.Identity.Name` is empty and you can see that from debugging? Are you actually logging in and able to see a non-empty name somewhere else (e.g. inside of your controller)?

Comment: No it doesn't work at all. When I log in, I know the context.User.Identity.Name isn't empty because my name appears on the menu. However, I think it happens too late for the logger.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn’t really answer my question. Can you please verify that your middleware is executed and whether `context.User.Identity.Name` is set inside your middleware (i.e. use the debugger to figure that out). And alternatively use `LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", "Test");` and check if your logs contain `Test` as the user name. – You have two separate concerns here (Serilog logging, and accessing the authenticated user) and we have no idea which of those two things is actually working for you.

Comment: I tried LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", "Test"); and it still appears as null. Thats strange.

Comment: Okay, so Serilog logging in general does not work. Can you show, how you have set up Serilog with ASP.NET Core? I.e. not just how you created your logger, but also how you are using it?

Comment: In general, the logging works. I get a message that I added to the question. Its just that the Test doesn't show up

Comment: So you do add Serilog to your host builder properly? From what I’ve read, you should put `LogContext.PushProperty` inside a `using` block, can you try doing that?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, I added it to WebHostBuilder already? And also, is there an example of using?

Comment: Where do I put the using block? Is it in program.cs?

Comment: *“No one has gotten usernames to work with Serilog so far.”* – From what you have written in the comments, you are unable to enrich your logging with constant values. So your problem has nothing to do with usernames.

Comment: I removed that comment. sorry.

Comment: I also am logging this to the database by the way so there is a Model structure that I follow

Comment: Then maybe log this to a more flexible medium for now to see whether the value is actually considered. I would recommend you to get the logging working properly first (maybe even in a separate project that has nothing to do with ASP.NET Core), and only then try to integrate this into ASP.NET Core.

Comment: There are too many variables here - I suggest trying to boil this down to a [mcve]. You can remove one thing at a time. Perhaps start by logging out to the Console Sink so that SQL Server is out of the problem area.

Comment: I edited the question. Turns out the Test property I pushed was appearing but due to the <property> tags, it didnt show up in the html page

Comment: Is it just the `"User logged in."` message you are looking at here when you're expecting to see the `Username` property being populated?

Comment: No, there are several fields one being the Message field that shows "User logged in", I noticed that the UserName property appears in my Properties field but only when it is hardcoded. I cannot set it from the httpcontext as it will be null

Comment: I'll edit the entire question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185549/discussion-between-kirk-larkin-and-jianya).

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that when I hardcoded a property, it would appear in my log under the properties tag. E.g. `LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", "Test")`
>
> ```xml
> <properties>
>     <property key='UserName'>Test</property>
> </properties>
> ```
>
> Also, I would like to bring it out of the properties tag and into its own field if possible.

The MSSqlServer sink for Serilog by default puts additional properties into the `Properties` column in its XML format. However, there is a way to [configure custom property columns](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#custom-property-columns) to move certain properties into its own properties. You can configure that using code but since you are using the [JSON-based configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#json-microsoftextensionsconfiguration) in `appsettings.json`, you can also do it there.

The configuration should look something like this (shortened the configuration here to show only the relevant parts):

```
"Serilog": {
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "MSSqlServer",
      "Args": {
        "connectionString": "…",
        "schemaName": "AnalyticsStudio",
        "tableName": "EventLogs",
        "columnOptionsSection": {
          "additionalColumns": [
            { "ColumnName": "UserName" }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The column is configured as a `varchar` by default, so it should work for your string value.

---

For properly filling the custom property see the following questions:

- [Serilog Additional Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32974560/216074) (for using Serilog for this in general)
- [Add user to the log context when using Serilog and Asp.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39896465/216074) (using ASP.NET Core 1.x but should still give the general idea)

---

[Kirk Larkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630078/kirk-larkin) suggested the following on chat:

> From your explanation so far, I'm wondering if you're expecting to see `UserName` in the message that is being logged as part of the same request that actually signs you in. If you are expecting this, it won't be the case because the `LogContext.PushProperty` call is happening before your call to something like `PasswordSignInAsync` (assuming you're using Identity).

If this is truly your situation, then you should know that your middleware that sets the custom property is running *before* any of your controller logic runs. So the custom property is set before the sign-in completed and as such, at the time the middleware ran, an empty username was added as a custom property. So the behavior is perfectly correct. It’s only for *subsequent* requests that the authentication middleware will be able to authenticate the user before your middleware runs so that you should see the correct username in your logging output.

There is not really a good way around this. Of course you could explicitly set the custom property again as you sign the user in. But I would recommend you against that as technically the request was still invoked without any authentication, so it shouldn’t be a problem not to have a username there.